# Bootstrap Button not working in mobile screen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```
<header id="header">

    <div class="container">

        <div class="logo float-left">
            <!-- Uncomment below if you prefer to use an image logo -->
            <h1 class="text-light">
                <a href="/" class="scrollto">
                    <span>E-Wallet</span>
                </a>
            </h1>
        </div>

        <nav class="main-nav float-right d-none d-lg-block">
            <ul>
                <!-- <li class="active"><a href="#intro">Home</a></li> -->
                <li>RM<input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" value="{{ request.user.balance }}" placeholder="00.00" readonly style="margin-top: 10px;width: 60px;">
                </li>
                <li style="margin-top: 10px">
                    <button 
                    data-url="{{ request.scheme }}://{{ request.get_host }}{% url 'reload' %}"{% if not can_reload %} disabled {% endif %} id="reload" type="button" class="btn btn-success">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Reload
                    </button>
                </li>


                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <li class="drop-down"> <a href="#">{{ user.username }}</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="{% url 'profile' %}" target="_blank">
                                Profile
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="{% url 'logout' %}" target="_blank">
                                Logout
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                {% else %}
                <li>
                    <a href="{% url 'login' %}" target="_blank">
                        Login
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="{% url 'register' %}" target="_blank">
                        Sign Up
                    </a>
                </li>
                {% endif %}
            </ul>
        </nav><!-- .main-nav -->
        
    </div>
</header>
```

The reload button is working when it is viewed from a laptop or a big screen, but whenever I'm trying to interact with it from the mobile screen, the button stops working. So far I have seen many examples, but now working with mine. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Whats do you mean by not working. e.g - you can not see it / you can not click on etc etc etc ? What is it !

Comment: I apology not to clearly say. The button is visible but whenever to click, it does not work. It works only in laptop screen

Comment: No need to aplogize :) Just add this information in your question as well. Please - Which button are you talking about the reload one ?

Comment: ```<button  data-url="{{ request.scheme }}://{{ request.get_host }}{% url 'reload' %}" {% if not can_reload %} disabled {% endif %} id="reload" type="button" class="btn btn-success">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Reload
                        </button>```

This reload button

Comment: It is clear that a li is overlaping your button. Try to find that div it'll work for you in the mobile version.

Comment: Can not find which one is overlapping.

Comment: @Ava still the same issue after update the code u suggested

Comment: In only formatted the code. That is not the answer. :)